# MongoDB Data reading from database

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I am using a database with a single document in a collection called "Counts". Entering that data is done by the code itself and after entering that data, the document looks like in the first picture.
After that I use the below code sample to read data.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );


     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "OneMedia" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

     DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("Counts");


        System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
        DBCursor curs = coll.find(); 
        Iterator<DBObject> fields = curs.iterator();

        while(fields.hasNext()){ 
        BasicDBList List = (BasicDBList) fields.next().get("counts");

        BasicDBObject object = (BasicDBObject) List.get(0); 
        Object value = object.get("comments_count"); /
            System.out.println("comments - " + value.toString());
        }
```

Every time I run that code to read data, the document in the collection duplicates and creates another document inside same collection.
Can some one please help me with this.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you running the code you added a new document. as you say. Since it added to the database it is there even you closed the programe. But if you need to delete all the data in the collection you can use `coll.drop()`; before you add new document into the database.

Comment: please, consider to accept the answer if you got help. It will helpful other with the same kind of issue.